# Downloading files from FTP Server where directory changed dynamically

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to download/upload files from FTP server.

How can I change `remote-directory="/directory Name"` dynamically in Spring FTP:Inbound-Channel.

My client will create a folder daily basically in `"MM-dd-yy"` format and copy all files there.
In "FTP:Inbound-channel" I did not find any way to configure this pattern. I basically have
to hardcord the directory or file names in configuration.
What I want is to set the path programatically. Because some times I need to download all files
from a direcotory or download only a specific file.

I found `"remote-directory-expression="'directory'+'/'+ new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(new java.util.Date())"` can be set in FTP:Outbound-channel
is there any such attribute in FTP:InBound-channel

My configuration is like this:

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${availableServerPort}" />
    <property name="username" value="${userid}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    cache-sessions="false" channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    filename-pattern="*.txt" auto-create-local-directory="true"
    delete-remote-files="false" remote-directory="/filedirectory"
    local-directory="${local_directory}">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
```

I did not find a way to do all the above items.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the inbound adapter, but the [<ftp:outbound-gateway/>](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) can be used to achieve what you need; described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway).

You can either use `ls` to list the files, followed a `<splitter/>` and another gateway using `get`; or you can use the `mget` command with a file name pattern in the expression.

The [FTP sample](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp) has an example of using the gateway